# Why do we need epochs?

Tags: machine-learning

In courses there is nothing about epochs, but in practice they are everywhere used.
Why do we need them if the optimizer finds the best weight in one pass. Why does the model improve?

Answer (score 6):

Generally whenever you want to optimize you use gradient descent. Gradient descent has a parameter called learning rate. In one iteration alone you can not guarantee that the gradient descent algorithm would converge to a local minima with the specified learning rate. That is the reason why you iterate again for the gradient descent to converge better.

Its also a good practice to change learning rates per epoch by observing the learning curves for better convergence.

Answer (score 4):

> Why do we need [to train several epochs] if the optimizer finds the best weight in one pass?

That's wrong in most cases. Gradient descent methods (see [a list of them](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/4582s0/overview_of_optimization_algorithms/)) does usually not find the optimal parameters (weights) in one pass. In fact, I have never seen any case where the optimal parameters were even reached (except for constructed cases).

One epoch consists of many weight update steps. One epoch means that the optimizer has used every training example once. Why do we need several epochs? Because gradient descent are iterative algorithms. It improves, but it just gets there in tiny steps. It only uses tiny steps, because it can only use local information. It does not have an idea of the function besides the current point at which it is.

You might want to read the gradient descent part of my [optimization basics](https://martin-thoma.com/optimization-basics/) blog post.